# Deleting selective data from MongoDB Secondary Only

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to delete data from a single Mongo secondary instance, by running delete command directly on a secondary, without affecting the primary and other secondary instances?

Explanation: I want to purge a large collection ~500 GB, having ~500 million records. I want to keep last few months data, so I will have to remove ~400 million records. It is a replica setup, with one primary and 2 secondaries. Storage Engine is WiredTiger. I do not want any downtime or slowness as it is a production DB of a live transactional system. I am thinking of below options:

1. Create a new collection, and copy last few months records in it, and drop the old one. But copying such huge data will slow down the DB server.
2. Take backup of entire collection, then run bulk delete, with a batch size of 1000. This will take weeks to delete so many records, also will create huge op logs, as every delete will produce an op log that will be synced to secondary. These op logs will take up huge disk space.
3. Another option is that I run bulk delete on one secondary only. Once the data is deleted, I promote it as primary. Then run same delete on other 2 secondary instances. This will not affect the prod environment. Hence the question: **Can we run delete on a secondary only? Once this secondary comes back in cluster after deletion, what will be the behaviour of the sync process between primary and secondary?**

Comment: I assume the oplog will be created anyway, no matter where you run the delete command, so you don't save any disk space. Even when you delete the data from a disconnected secondary node, I assume it will take a long time (which you will have three times). I would say: even if such an approach will work you do not save any time or disk space.

Comment: Even if able to remove, WiredTiger won't free disc space untill you run `compact` which slow down your secondary node during hours

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Can I not delete the oplog from a disconnected secondary without affecting anything else? Long time is still manageable, as major concern is to reduce prod downtime and slowness.

Comment: @Valijon yes disk space will not be freed, but it can be reused by future writes and disk space usage growth will slow down. Also with only last few months data on prod, select queries will be faster.

Comment: Once you have cleanup your database (no matter how you are gonna doing it), you should consider [TTL Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/)

Comment: In a Replica Set it is the purpose to get an exact copy from PRIMARY at the SECONDARY. You cannot modify any data on SECONDARY, all changes have to be done on the PRIMARY - simply take these as a facts. If you like to cheat such main design principle do it on your own risk.

Comment: What was your final action?

Trying with a TTL caused an increasing replica lag at peak time, as the system doesn't reduce the TTL index deletion according to the pressure form other queries.
And the full process is taking almost a month.

Solution 2 is taking months and also caused huge replication lag is the cluster is a bit stressed by other queries

Answer (score 1):

I run a small test on a local MongoDB cluster. In principle it seems to work when you follow this procedure:

1. Shut down the Secondary
2. [Restart the secondary as a standalone](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members/#restart-the-secondary-as-a-standalone-on-a-different-port) (you cannot perform any changes on SECONDARY)
3. Connect to the standalone and delete old data
4. Shutdown the standalone
5. Restart the standalone normally as ReplicaSet member
6. Repeat step (1) to (5) with the other Secondary. You may run above steps in parallel on all Secondaries, however then you have no redundancy in case of problems.
7. Set a Secondary from above to Primary
8. Repeat step (1) to (5) with the last node

As I said, I did a "quick and dirty" test with a few documents and it seems to work.

However, **I don't think it will work in your setup** because:

Step (5) "delete old data" will take some time, maybe some hours or even days. When you have finished deletion, most likely you will trap into this situation:

[Resync a Member of a Replica Set:](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/)

> A replica set member becomes "stale" when its replication process falls so far behind that the primary overwrites oplog entries the member has not yet replicated. The member cannot catch up and becomes "stale." When this occurs, **you must completely resynchronize the member** by removing its data and performing an initial sync.

I.e. you will add all deleted data again.

Perhaps there are hacks to overwrite "stale" to "SECONDARY". Then you would have to drop old PRIMARY and add it again as SECONDARY. But by this you would loose all data which have been newly inserted in production while step (5) was running. I assume the application is constantly inserting new data (otherwise you would not get such an amount of documents), such data would be lost.

Comment: Then any other approach you can suggest to delete this data?

Comment: Can I do this: Keep secondary in the cluster and run a background delete on it. So it is replicating the new inserts, and also deleting the old data. During this time, I will not send any traffic on this node from the application, so prod will not experience any slowness. Then I can repeat this with all secondary nodes. Then make one of the secondary as primary, and then do the same process on old primary.

Comment: No, as long as your node is part of a ReplicatSet you cannot perform any modifications on it (`rs.slaveOk()` applies only for reading data). But when you run node as standalone then it does not receive any oplog's, i.e. it does not receive anything from the PRIMARY.

Comment: So am I left with option 1 and 2 only (as mentioned in my original question)? Which one of both is better?

Comment: I think option 1 will be better, if you have sufficient disk space and you can handle ongoing traffic. Consider an TTL index on the new collection.

Comment: In 2nd point, I mentioned that oplog size will increase if I run bulk delete. But oplog has been implemented as a circular buffer. So its size can't become very large. So does it mean that bulk delete will not use huge disk space?

Comment: could you please reply @Wernfried?

Comment: If the circular oplog buffer restarts the circle then for sure the secondary becomes STALE you have to run a inital (i.e. full) sync

Comment: what do you mean by "restarts the circle"? Does it mean that circular buffers fills up before the secondary could replicate all logs in it, and then these logs are overwritten and never synced to secondary? If I put a sleep() operation between delete operations, will it help?

Comment: could you please reply @Wernfried?

Comment: I gave a statement already: You cannot delete selective data from Secondary only - period!

Comment: no no. My comment above regarding circular buffer was if I delete from primary.

Comment: I don't know, try it out.

Comment: So doing mulitple smaller iteration of: set-as-primary, cleanup, add-into-cluster by operation of one hour or so could be a solution?

Comment: May work, however I don't see any benefit to deleting the data normally.